# appendChild throwing an error for xml data

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a xml data like this.

```
<ROOT  START="0" END="100"  TITLE=""  >
    <DATA>
        <IP ID="TEXT" FLG="0">
            <G VAL1="value1"  MyFlg="0"/>
            <G VAL1="value1"  MyFlg="1"/>
        </IP>
    </DATA>
</ROOT>
```

I wanted to append one child node to this xml file. For that here is my

```
code

        var gTAgXMLxmlString = "<F></F>";
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var GInpXML = parser.parseFromString(gTAgXMLxmlString, "text/xml");
        var gTAgInpXMLValues = GInpXML.getElementsByTagName('F')[0];

        gTAgInpXMLValues.setAttribute("VAL1","");
        gTAgInpXMLValues.setAttribute("MyFlg","");

         RootEle.appendChild(gTAgInpXMLValues)
```

Note : RootEle is my Initial xml.

Things are coming fine in chrome.  SO My xml data will be

```
<ROOT  START="0" END="100"  TITLE=""  >
    <DATA>
        <IP ID="TEXT" FLG="0">
            <G VAL1="value1"  MyFlg="0"/>
            <G VAL1="value1"  MyFlg="1"/>
        </IP>
    </DATA>
    <G VAL1="value1"  MyFlg="0"/>
</ROOT>
```

But this line `RootEle.appendChild(gTAgInpXMLValues)` is failing in IE. Any workaround for this.

Comment: Please create a working snippet using `<>` to replicate the issue?

Comment: Please show how RootEle is created

Comment: @Maluen Root element I am taking from backend.

Comment: @David Show the code you are using to parse the string you are getting from the backend to an actual XML document.